# Github Desktop (macos) - Update from master vs Merge into Current Branch

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I have looked around quite a bit but could not find an answer specific to Github Desktop.

I have two main branches Master and Develop.

When I develop a new feature I do the following:

1. Create a feature branch from Develop
2. When I am happy with the new feature I switch back to Develop
3. Select Merge into Current Branch to update develop
4. Delete the feature branch

Sometimes though, I need to do a little fix in Master. The approach that I use is the same, but now I would like to update Develop with the bug fix in Master (if needed).

At the moment I do the following:

1. Select the Develop branch
2. Then Update from master
3. Solve conflicts if any
4. Continue my development in Develop

The fact is that there is a different option available in Github **Desktop**, Merge into current branch.

I have never used it, but I would like to understand if I should.

Comment: They sound like the same thing to me, but "update from master" has already chosen a branch to merge into the current branch.